# Preprocessing text data with TFRecords files

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tfrecord

I have a .tfrecord dataset of text documents (emails) with corresponding labels '0' or '1' (for spam/non-spam). All of this dataset is already in the form of a .tfrecord file. I'm trying to  turn the emails into a bag-of-words representation. I have all the helper methods to do it, but I'm still not familiar with tfrecords. This is what I have so far to read the tf_record file:

```
def read_from_tfrecord(filenames):

    tfrecord_file_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filenames], name='queue')
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    _, tfrecord_serialized = reader.read(tfrecord_file_queue)

    tfrecord_features = tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord_serialized,
                        features={
                            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                            'text': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                        }, name='features')

    text = tfrecord_features['text']
    label = tfrecord_features['label']

    return label, text
```

How should I proceed if I want to use my helper methods to modify the 'texts' ?

Answer (score 0):

`tf.parse_single_example` will return a dictionary mapping keys to tensors, meaning that `text` is a tensor. Thus you can use tensor operations to convert it to a bag of words.

For example:

```
text = tf.unique(tf.string_split([text]).values).y
```

This will return all the unique tokens (split by spaces) in the email. You'd probably have to add more operations to handle punctuation and other cases.